# imageview draw issue with asynctask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Have the following asynctask that i'm using to download some images.  Works fine except for the very first image, which doesn't always appears unless I do something like move to the next image and then back again.

```
public class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    static ImageView _imageView=null;

    public DownloadImageTask(ImageView ctl){
        _imageView=ctl;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        _imageView.setImageBitmap(result);
    }
    ...
}
```

I thought this might be an issue with updating the UI on a background thread, so I reworked this using an abstract class that invokes a method on the UI thread that calls .setImageBitmap() but I still get the same behaviour - works fine for all images except the first, unless I move to the next image and back again.

Is there a way to force a redraw on the imageview after i set the image?

Comment: Shouldn't be an issue around calling from the background thread as `onPostExecute` should execute in the UI thread. Where in the Activity lifecycle are you calling this AsyncTask from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar issue, and what I did in my `Activity.onCreate()` was something like this:

```
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.myListView);
adapter = new MyArrayAdapter(this, myArray, ...);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
if (myArray.size() > 0)
{
    // Fake a click on the first item
    onItemClick(listView, myArray, 0, 0);
}
```

Then, `onItemClick()` does what is required to find the `ImageView` for the current row. Of course, without seeing your code, the above is just a wild guess...

Comment: In the current version my activity extends a class with an abstract method: setImageBitmap(), which gets called by the AsyncTask task.  public class MyActivity extends DownloadImageActivity{


    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
    
 ...
        new DownloadImageTask(MyActivity.this).execute(s);
    }

    public void setImageBitmap(Bitmap bitmap){
     ImageView img=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img1);
     img.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }
}